# Integration of Google drive in Android Apps?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I need to upload files to Google drive and see/download the files i had uploaded in my android application.How to do this in the simplest way..?Any suggestions ,sample codes,explanations to do this are welcomed. Thanking you in advance .

PS:WITHOUT INSTALLING GOOGLE DRIVE IN DEVICE..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to follow the [Android quickstart guide for Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android)

It explains how to build an Android application that uploads photos to Drive in less than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Google has deprecated Google Drive API for Android. So we have to use REST API.

Use this answer and check if it useful.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59063198/9538854

Answer (score 0):

Refer this, [Complete Step by Step Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android)

Code for Uploading Only (I am still figuring out how to browse files):

```
package com.example.drivequickstart;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1;
    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 2;
    static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 3;

    private static Uri fileUri;
    private static Drive service;
    private GoogleAccountCredential credential;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    service = getDriveService(credential);
                    startCameraIntent();
                }
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                saveFileToDrive();
            } else {
                startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
            }
            break;
        case CAPTURE_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                saveFileToDrive();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startCameraIntent() {
        String mediaStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(mediaStorageDir + java.io.File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg"));

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
    }

    private void saveFileToDrive() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // File's binary content
                    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
                    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", fileContent);

                    // File's metadata.
                    File body = new File();
                    body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
                    body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");

                    File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
                    if (file != null) {
                        showToast("Photo uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
                        startCameraIntent();
                    }
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
    }

    public void showToast(final String toast) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google drive is accessible through the Google Drive API, the sample demo is created by the android folks at the below path which is very helpful and provides a sample of all the capabilities. please follow the below link
[Git hub demo for Google Drive API](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos.git)