# Is there any way to programmatically upload files from Android application to Google Drive?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have an usecase where I have to upload an image taken from my android application to a Google drive folder. I have gone through the Drive Android SDK documentation but found out that they have deprecated the API recently. Is there any other way or cloud storage where I can upload the images in a sharable folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can someone provide an up-to-date Android guide for Google Drive REST API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949872/can-someone-provide-an-up-to-date-android-guide-for-google-drive-rest-api-v3)

Comment: I have successfully uploaded images, created folders in Google Drive by following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59063198/6419026

Try this, It will work.